# How to build a custom grid or find an existing one

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, telerik

This is a grid from a Silver Light application. I am writing another application in ASP.NET MVC that needs to have the same look, so IK am asking if this is something I can find in Telerik or Bootstrap or jQuery UI ? and if I have to build it completely custom then where I even begin from ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the abstract markup that could represent such a box.

```
<div id="criteria_container" class="search_box">
  <div id="criteria_operations">
    <span id="criteria_add" class="criteria_op">+</span>
    <span id="criteria_subtract" class="criteria_op">-</span>
    <span id="criteria_swap" class="criteria_op">></span>
  </div>
  <div id="criteria_box">
    <div id="criteria_header">Search Criteria</div>
    <div id="criteria_results"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then, as somewhere to start.

Although I haven't cascaded any of the CSS styles, you may want to. Before you do, note that many take issue with the nesting of styles as both as a [semantic issue](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/avoid-nested-selectors-for-more-modular-css) and as a potential inefficiency in certain applications.

```
 #criteria_container {
   width: 600px;
   height: 100px;
   border: solid 1px black;
 }

 #criteria_operations {
   width: 10px;
   height: 100%;
   float: left;
   background-color: #aaaaaa;
   border: solid 1px black;
 }

 #criteria_header {
   text-align: center;
   background-color: #aaaaaa;
   border: solid 1px black;
 }

 .criteria_op {
 }

 #criteria_box {
   width: 588px;
   float: right;
 }
```